# gnuplot cursor not moving on OSX 10.9?

Tags: gnuplot, osx-mavericks

I have recently installed OSX 10.9, with the latest version of XQuartz and gnuplot 4.6.4

When I move the cursor across the gnuplot window the coordinates shown in the bottom left corner do not update. I am testing this using `plot sin(x)`. The desired functionality I am describing is seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbUnTCirTA0&t=0m48s).

I believe that this was working under OSX 10.7, so I am not sure what is the problem.

Comment: Which terminal do you use? `aqua`, `wxt` or `x11`?

Comment: Don't know what the problem might be, since I don't use OSX, but did you try out the `wxt` terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing gnuplot through macports instead of building from the official sourceforge download site solved the issue.

I also installed the `wxt` terminal while I was at it since it offers some improved features, but `x11` works fine too. (Thanks @Christoph for bringing me to learn about `wxt`).

Instructions:

1. Install [macports](http://www.macports.org/install.php)
2. Open the terminal and enter `port variants gnuplot` followed by `sudo port install gnuplot +wxwidgets`

(Note: the installation may take a while, but is all automated)